# json array with null

Tags: json, put

Below is the JSON that is parsed to validate PUT request body:

```
{
    "requestKey": "whatever",
    "shoppingList": []
}
```

---

As part of testing, we are seeing another scenario coming, which is also a valid JSON:

```
{
    "requestKey": "whatever",
    "shoppingList": [null]
}
```

---

`[]` signifies empty shopping list. What does `[null]` signify?

How `[null]` different from `[]`? for `shoppingList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` in this case and as referenced in [RFC 7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) means that the shoppingList is an array containing one primitive null value.

At least semantically it should yield in (Source example is in Java):

```
shoppingList.get(0) -> null
```

Whereas an empty array should yield in:

```
shoppingList.get(0) -> IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Which is exactly the behaviour you see in the current version of Google Chrome:

```
let myObj = {
    "requestKey": "whatever",
    "shoppingList": [null]
};
undefined
myObj
{requestKey: 'whatever', shoppingList: Array(1)}requestKey: "whatever"shoppingList: Array(1)0: nulllength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)[[Prototype]]: Object
let myObj = {
    "requestKey": "whatever",
    "shoppingList": []
};
undefined
myObj
{requestKey: 'whatever', shoppingList: Array(0)}requestKey: "whatever"shoppingList: [][[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: You mean, array of length one

Comment: Yes. It's an array with the length 1 where [0] = null.